# Problem with an image that is always in the first plan

Tags: iphone, animation, view, sdk, set

so I have a tab bar application and I have put a effect like tweeter, when you push a button from the tab bar, a arrow slide to the selected button, it's a really cool "animation"
But the problem is this arrow is always in my first plan, when (for example) I want to play a video in full screen the arrow is already there, to when i switch to an other view without any tab bar, the arrow still there...

My code is in the AppDelegate.
in the .h i have that:

```
AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

UIImageView *tabBarArrow;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *tabBarArrow;


- (CGFloat) horizontalLocationFor:(NSUInteger)tabIndex;
- (void) addTabBarArrow;
```

and in my .m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    _tabBarController.delegate = self;
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self addTabBarArrow];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void) addTabBarArrow {
    UIImage* tabBarArrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow.png"];
    self.tabBarArrow = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tabBarArrowImage] autorelease];
    CGFloat verticalLocation = self.window.frame.size.height - _tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height
    - tabBarArrowImage.size.height + 6;
    tabBarArrow.frame = CGRectMake([self horizontalLocationFor:0], verticalLocation,
                                   tabBarArrowImage.size.width, tabBarArrowImage.size.height);

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarArrow];
}

-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    CGRect frame = tabBarArrow.frame;
    frame.origin.x = [self horizontalLocationFor:_tabBarController.selectedIndex];
    tabBarArrow.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(CGFloat) horizontalLocationFor:(NSUInteger)tabIndex{
    CGFloat tabItemWidth = _tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width / _tabBarController.tabBar.items.count;
    CGFloat halfTabItemWidth = (tabItemWidth / 2.0) - (tabBarArrow.frame.size.width / 2.0);

    return (tabIndex * tabItemWidth) + halfTabItemWidth;
}
```

I think thats all
thanks to help me because I really don't know how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure its not what you wanted to know but here is already a source code for that http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bctabbarcontroller

otherwise if you like to adapt your own logic you will need to hide the image view on specific changes like opening a full screen movie.

Comment: yes, i'll see that, but the problem with the fullscreen video is that I use the mobile version of YouTube so I don't have any code for that..

Answer (score 0):

Or try this in your `UITabBarController` class:

```
- (void)hideTabBar
{
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            view.hidden = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```